# Cannot install the original GNOME DE on my PC

Tags: gnome, icons, workspaces, cinnamon, desktop-icons

A few months ago I really needed a way to arrange icons on my desktop (or something similar, I can't distinctly remember), but I was not able to do it on the original desktop. I searched a little online and somewhere it was written that GNOME desktop supports very limited functionality, and I could consider switching to Cinnamon based desktop while still being in GNOME desktop environment. I did so and was very happy with the results. Today, I upgraded my OS to Ubuntu 20.10 and I loved the gestures features, especially the toggling between the workspaces. But somehow, the icons on my desktop showed over everything while transitioning. Here's a sample:

[image]

I thought the different desktop was the reason for this, and thus tried to search what changes I had made so that I could reverse it to the original desktop. But to my dismay, my browser history showed no fruitful results with any desired keywords. I couldn't find the page I used to make the changes. I cannot find out what's the difference between a default desktop and the one I am using. Here's the output for `screenfetch`:

[image]

As far as I can tell, everything is set to defaults, but my desktop is still different. I even tried running:

```
sudo apt install gnome
```

and it did install something worth 200 MB (I don't know what) but it did not alter my desktop at all! Here's the screenshot of my desktop, (**with smaller icons and a different right-click desktop menu**)

[image]

It would be very helpful if someone could tell me a way to change my desktop to the original one. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 21.10 uses Gnome 40 it is different at least a bit. That is what 21.10 comes with.

Comment: Just install the normal gnome desktop by ```sudo taskel install gnome-session```

Comment: If all fails, consider a fresh install. An upgrade caries over all kind of old configuration settings, including eventually misconfiguration. The pictures you show are Gnome Shell, not cinnamon. That is also what Screenfetch tells.

Comment: @AkshajSingla it shows gnome-session is already at its latest version

Comment: @ProfessorofStupidity IDK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, it was not Gnome that needed to be installed, but Ubuntu-Desktop. Simply run the command

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

And now my desktop is back to the original one and the icons are not overlaying the screen while transitioning workspaces.

[image]